# What is the most effecient way to write application code?

Tags: android

I am new to android application developement.
How can I write efficient and optimized code? Can anyone give me a tutorial or example source with explanation.

Comment: Not all circumstances actually require efficiency. Do you have an app which is running too slowly? If so, then yeah, optimize it. Otherwise don't worry about it. I think most Android development is in Java, so whatever techniques are used for Java optimization in general should apply for Android in particular.

Comment: Good books on general coding that I read: Code Complete Steve McConnell and Effective Java by Bloch

Answer (score 0):

I have no clue what you expect here, but start with the manual?

- [Hello world](http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/hello-world.html) is a good place to start
- Read up on [apllication fundamentals](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html)